# Raster to postgis - choosing right projection

Tags: postgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have a raster with the projection:

```
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

I'm trying to insert a raster file into the postgis with a SRID 4326, but I don't know if it is right.

```
raster2pgsql -s <srid> -I -C -M <pathRaster> -F  -f rast public.rasterTable
```

How can I figure out the right SRID to every projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look it up at http://spatialreference.org, SR-ORG:7917 is suggested as an exact match and you also get an INSERT line to add it to the lookup table.

It won't say if there a relevant difference for your data, so you'll have to do some digging yourself. The change from 4326 is the `+towgs` parameter versus the `+no_defs` one.